# Falta de conexão com servidor via HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, url, conexão, progress-bar

Tenho uma aplicação que faz consulta em uma URL através do seguinte método dentro de uma `AsyncTask`:

```
 try {
            HttpURLConnection http = getHttpUrlConnection("http://www.sitedoservidor.com.br");
            if (http != null) {
                http.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "flag=0");
                http.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                http.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                http.setReadTimeout(10000);
                http.connect();

                Map<String, List<String>> reqMap = http.getHeaderFields();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : reqMap.entrySet()) {
                    for (String i : e.getValue()) {
                        if (e.getKey() != null && e.getKey().startsWith("Set-Cookie") && i.contains("SESSION")) {
                            sessionId = i.split(";")[0].trim();
                        }
                    }
                }

                http.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Logo que o método é chamado, aciono o `ProgressDialog` até que o método retorne o resultado desejado.

Para que o usuário saiba que a função ainda está em funcionamento, parametrizei `progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` para que feche somente após o retorno do método esperado, sem que o usuário feche o *app* ou saia da `Activity` por acidente.

O problema é que eventualmente, se o servidor está fora do ar, a aplicação congela no `http.connect()` e praticamente trava a aplicação, pois o `ProgressDialog` continua em funcionamento.

Como posso tratar esse erro para que quando o servidor estiver fora do ar, a `AsyncTask` pare, feche o `ProgressDialog` e assim avisar o usuário de que não foi possível completar a ação ou que a URL está fora do ar?

Comment: Quando da esse erro, cai no ```catch (IOException ex) {```?

Comment: Não.  Ele simplesmente congela.  Gostaria de pelo menos um método para testar a conexão com a URL e que depois de um determinado tempo, sem resposta do servidor, ele fosse para 'catch (IOException ex)'

Comment: Adicionei um código que pode te ajudar, da uma olhada na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Rogério, você pode fazer dessa forma:

Adiciona mais um catch, que será responsável por observar o TimeOut, caso estoure o tempo sem resposta do servidor, irá cair nele, ai é só remover o ProgressDialog

```
try {
            HttpURLConnection http = getHttpUrlConnection("http://www.sitedoservidor.com.br");
            if (http != null) {
                http.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "flag=0");
                http.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                http.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                http.setReadTimeout(10000);
                http.connect();

                Map<String, List<String>> reqMap = http.getHeaderFields();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : reqMap.entrySet()) {
                    for (String i : e.getValue()) {
                        if (e.getKey() != null && e.getKey().startsWith("Set-Cookie") && i.contains("SESSION")) {
                            sessionId = i.split(";")[0].trim();
                        }
                    }
                }

                http.disconnect();
            }
        }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        //remove o loader aqui

        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

O *SocketTimeoutException* deve vir antes do *IOException*

Comment: Muito obrigado Leonardo pela sugestão.  No momento a URL está funcionando perfeitamente e assim nao consigo testar.  Logo que tiver um resultado, postarei aqui.  Muito obrigado mais uma vez.